# Turbo C++ выдает странное значение

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пробовал вводить и целые значения, и с плавающей точкой, бесполезно.

Comment: А ты файл сохранял перед компиляцией? Потому что там звёздочка, что он не сохранён.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй double использовать, есть вероятность, что delH выходит за пределы памяти.

Comment: Действительно, поменял тип и сразу пошло дело. Благодарю)

Comment: Начинать надо с http://people.toiit.sgu.ru/Sinelnikov/PT/C/Kern_Ritch.pdf у них еще зеленая старая была, читай, смотри.

Comment: В си очень строго с памятью

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry, а какое отношение арифметическое переполнение имеет  к памяти?

Comment: Может быть и арифметическое переполнение. Обычно, когда идет заход за память переменной выводится отрицательное число или кракозябора. К тому же мы не знаем что он вводит в tau. В случае переполнения программа просто виснет, но ихмо виснуть тут нечему(хотя есть вариант, что он зашел за лимиты и завис). Известно, что тип float имеет 4 байта и больше четырех знаков до запятой и после запятой быть не может. Самое простое, где это можно проверить "cheat engine"